# C++ error: 'No suitable conversion function from [class name] to “void *"

Tags: c++, callback, memcpy

I am trying to copy 2 arrays since the conventional method of copying is not giving me the updated value. So I am trying via the [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) method

```
ret_t ifxPkc:: regSCM0ReadCB(uint32 idx,tlm::tlm_generic_payload& p)
{

    memcpy(scmr0Reg_,scMem, sizeof(scmr0Reg_));

    return scmr0Reg_[idx].read(p);
}
```

This is a callback function. Here the `idx` is incremented for every call by another piece of code.

`scmr0Reg_` belongs to `IfxPkcScmR0Register` class. 
Further, `IfxPkcScmR0Register` belongs to

```
class IfxPkcScmR0Register : public SC_BSX::IdxReg32
```

On using in the above format I get the error -

**C++ error: 'No suitable conversion function from [class name] to “void *"**

Can I get help on how do I need to use it in [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) function ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please document a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want somebody to understand what happened here. This is important both for us being able to help you, and also for others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memcpy takes pointers as first two parameters. Since it is not obvious from your code what are the data types of `scmr0Reg_` and `scMem`, I assume they are some objects. In this case you need to pass pointers to them as `memcpy(&scmr0Reg_, &scMem...`

Comment: Thank You @dmi the error has gone. `scMem` is of type `unsigned long scMem[128]`

Comment: @KarthikRao Then you should not write `&scMem`.

Comment: @rozina You are right, the error has gone, but code is breaking. My primary issue is that `scMem` has the latest value and when I want to copy it to `scmr0Reg_` it is not updating. Initially instead of memcpy I directly wrote `scmr0Reg_[idx] = scMem[idx];`  which is not working, so I resorted to `memcpy` Any other clarifications needed I can provide.

Comment: I just noticed, what is the data type of scmr0Reg? Is it a class (just below you call a method of it)?

Comment: The datatype of `scmr0Reg_` is `IfxPkcScmR0Register            scmr0Reg_;` . `IfxPkcScmR0Register` is a class.  .Further, `IfxPkcScmR0Register` belongs to

             `class IfxPkcScmR0Register : public SC_BSX::IdxReg32`

Comment: The important is if the scmr0Reg_ **is** a class. If yes, you cannot memcpy to it because you overwrite then all members including vptr. It will compile but never work runtime. The data type of the first parameter of memcpy should be a memory array. It may be for example an array which is a member of your class.